# If Orach Chayim 53:14 prohibits 'memorized' Torah recited by the Blind, Why are synagogues allowed to hear 'memorized' Qere [during Torah portion]?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, torah-reading

**If spoken קְרִי‎ Qere corrections are never written in any Torah (but memorized like a Blind recitation : Orach Chayim 53:14), Why are synagogues allowed to hear Qere [during Torah portion]?**

[Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 53:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.53.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> One who is blind may go down before the ark, as long as he does not read from the Torah, because things that are written, you do not have permission to say them by heart. (סומא יורד לפני התיבה ובלבד שלא יקרא בתורה משום דברים שבכתב אי אתה רשאי לאומרם על פה)

[Contemporary Halakhic Problems, Vol II, Part I, Chapter II Blessings and Rituals 12]

> There is a general prohibition against the reading of even a single word of the Written Law from memory (Gittin 60b; Rambam, Hilkhot Tefillah 12:8; Shulḥan Arukh, Oraḥ Hayyim 53:14; and Yoreh De'ah 139:3). The Written Law may be read or studied only from a written text. Even though Magen Avraham, Oraḥ Hayyim 49:1, indicates that this restriction is relaxed in the case of a blind person who would otherwise be prevented from studying Torah, the public reading of the Torah on prescribed occasions requires that the appropriate portion be read from a Torah scroll and not be recited from memory.

**Why can קְרִי‎ 'Qri' corrections be recited from memory, but reciting the entire Torah from memory is prohibited?**

Comment: Whoever told you to not recite things by heart generally told you to recite this word by heart. In other words, you can ask why there is a thing called kri/ktiv but I don't get this question at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I struggle to understand why souls that may fumble to remember 'Kri' of Torah can recite it (with assistance), but the blind who know It all by heart are denied that privilege.

Comment: Vowels aren't marked either and we read them by heart. So should we omit them?

Comment: @Kazibácsi - Exactly! The halakhic prohibition against Blind Torah is due to 'memorized' words. - so Why are 'Qri' words even allowed? If 'Qri' words are allowed, then Blind Torah recitation should also be allowed.

Comment: Your concept of reading by memory is flawed. If you have the written text in front of you and you have the oral tradition (including ketiv-qerei, vowels, cantillation) in your mind, that's not reciting by heart.

Comment: @חידה if your question is why did God make a rule that words that are written need to be read from writing, you can ask that. But what you wrote here is different and doesn't seem compelling to me as a question at all